# Serial serial upvoting - a reverse psychology attack?

Tags: support, serial-voting

So yesterday someone upvoted more than 10 of my Questions and Answers within about a minute of each other. I recognized what it was, serial upvoting, even though it had never happened to me before. As I expected (and is right) the whole thing was reversed a few hours later.

But now today it's happened again, with even *more* posts. I expect it'll be reversed again, and it should.

I have not received any gushing comments on a recent answer that would lead me to believe that someone found it so helpful that they want to upvote *all* of my other posts.

Is it possible that someone is trying to make it look like I'm sockpuppeting my way to higher reputation and, thus, get me suspended? I don't know what the point would be; I'm already over 10K and the privs one gets at 20K aren't *that* compelling. And I'm certainly not in it to be at the top of the Reputation leader board.

I'm baffled, frankly.

---

2012-10-05: Here we go again.

Comment: I guess, you're just doing a bloody good job in editing and commenting... what's baffled me is this - are you working full-time, how you find the time to do all that is mind-blowing! :)

Comment: I am working full-time, but I find five minutes here, ten minutes there...

Comment: I'm not sure we can help you guess at people's motives, Al....

Comment: Well, it didn't happen again yesterday. I guess they got bored.

Comment: Must be a love-sick stalker XD